# Scala: how to implement via function object parameters a generic flow where signatures differ?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, idioms

I am a Java programmer taking baby steps into Scala programming.

I have defined a function similar to (which may be *idiomatically wrong*, I wouldn't know...):

```
def someGenericAlgorithm(param1: String, param1: String, param3: String) = {

    val triedResult1 = someFunction(param1)
    triedResult1 match {
      case Success(result1) =>
        val triedResult2 = someOtherFunction(param2)
        triedResult2 match {
          case Success(result2) =>
            val triedPolymorphicResult = someToBeReplacedAccordingToSpecificLogicFunction(result1, result2, param3)
            triedPolymorphicResult match {
              case Success(polymorphicResult) =>
                doSomethingGeneric(polymorphicResult)                    
                ....
              case Failure(exception) =>
                ....
            }
          case Failure(exception) =>
            ....
        }
      case Failure(exception) =>
        ....
    }
  }
```

So the function receives 3 parameters, processes the first two in sequence, takes the results of the processing and passes it along to the `someToBeReplacedAccordingToSpecificLogicFunction` along side the third parameter.

Now I wish to write a similar function in that the first two function calls are present, the error logic is the same, and the only difference is that the `someToBeReplacedAccordingToSpecificLogicFunction` is now `aReplacementLogicFunction` instead.

Had the two functions had the same signature, I guess that would not have been a problem, but, they do not, the `aReplacementLogicFunction` has different parameters, more specifically, two more parameters. You may say then, that I could just pass in `Option` parameters where these two `Option`s are `None`s in the first case and in that way I would have aligned my two functions to be of the same signature, thus:

```
def someToBeReplacedAccordingToSpecificLogicFunction(result1: Int, result2: Int, param3: String, unused1:Option[String] = None, unused2:Option[String] = None)

def aReplacementLogicFunction(result1: Int, result2: Int, param3: String, used1:Option[String], used2:Option[String])
```

***But***, a third flow exists where the nonexistent arguments of the first function are of a different kind, say MyClass, e.g.:

```
def anotherReplacementLogicFunction(result1: Int, result2: Int, param3: String, used1: MyClass, used2: MyClass)
```

*The question is*, then, how would I generify these functions to be passed along to some refactored generic algorithm function that would receive a function as a parameter. Is there a way to define something like:

```
def refactoredOutCoreLogic(param1: String, param1: String, param3: String, polimorphicFunction: SignatureUnknown)
```

To answer my own question in **Java**:

The way in which I would have solved this in Java is to have defined a class hierarchy akin to:

```
abstract class ResultKeeperRunnable implements Runnable {
    protected int param1, param2;
    void setParam1(...) {...}
    void setParam2(...) {...}
}

class SomeToBeReplacedAccordingToSpecificLogicFunctionClass extends ResultKeeperRunnable  {
    String param3;
    // ctor receiving all params omitted for brevity 
    void run() {
      // do specific Logic
    }
}

class AReplacementLogicFunctionClass extends ResultKeeperRunnable {
    String param3, param4, param5;
    // ctor receiving all params omitted for brevity 
    void run() {
      // do specific Logic
    }
}

class AnotherReplacementLogicFunctionClass extends ResultKeeperRunnable {
    String param3;
    MyClass param4, param5;
    // ctor receiving all params omitted for brevity 
    void run() {
      // do specific Logic
    }
}
```

Finally the factored out core logic method would be something like:

```
void refactoredOutCoreLogic(String param1, String param2, String param3, ResultKeeperRunnable polimorphicLogic) {
    // error handling logic removed for brevity
    int result1 = someMethod(param1);
    int result2 = someOtherMethod(param2);
    polymorphicLogic.setParam1(result1);
    polymorphicLogic.setParam2(result2);
    polymorphicLogic.run()
    ...

}
```

Will the Scala solution, be no more of a syntactically different clone of the Java solution presented above? It seems as if there should be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have* a function that takes `result1`, `result2`, and a bunch of other parameters.

You *want* a function that just takes `result1` and `result2`.

To do this, use [partial application](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html).  Write your replaceable functions curried like this with a second set of parentheses at the end holding the common parameters:

```
def aReplacementLogicFunction(param3: String, used1:Option[String], used2:Option[String])(result1: Int, result2: Int)
```

Then pass the partially applied function into your common function like this:

```
someGenericAlgorithm(param1, param2, aReplacementLogicFunction(param3, used1, used2))
```

As far as the generic algorithm is concerned, it has absolutely no knowledge of the extra parameters.  Those are all applied before calling the function.

Comment: Thanks @Karl its a beautiful and elegant solution!